# HTML Bootstrap div height should occupied all remaining space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CRIBBEO</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" sizes="64x64" /> 

</head>
<body style="background-color: #6a9acd">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"  style="background-color: #486A86;color:white;height: 60px">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- add header -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: white" href="#">Cribbeo</a>
            </div>
            <!-- menu items -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a style="color: white" href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a style="color: white" href="#">Ayuda</a></li>
                    <li><a style="color: white" href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- social media icons -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook" style="font-size:26px;color:white"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-instagram" style="font-size:26px;color:white"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter" style="font-size:26px;color:white"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-youtube" style="font-size:26px;color:white"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="container-fluid fill"  >
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-md-6" style="color:white;background-color: red; height: 100%">



                <div style="margin: auto;">
                    <img  src="images/logohorizontal.png" alt="Cribbeo" width="200px">


                    <H4>
                        EL MERCADO DE PIEZAS DE SEGUNDA MANO ESTA A PUNTO DE CAMBIAR
                    </H4>

                    <H1  >
                        ¿ QUIERES FORMAR PARTE?
                    </H1>

                    <div class="logo_tiendas">

                        <img src="images/app-store.png" alt="Cribbeo App" width="204" height="62">
                        <img src="images/play-store.png" alt="Cribbeo App" width="204" height="62">
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="color:white;background-color: yellow">
                <div class="row">
                    adios
                </div>

            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" style="background-color: #486A86;color:white;height: 60px">
            <div class="container" >

            </div>


        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    </body>

    </html>
```

And this is the file custom.css:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #777;
}

.social .fa-facebook:hover {
    color: #4060A5;
}

.social .fa-twitter:hover {
    color: #00ABE3;
}

.social .fa-google-plus:hover {
    color: #e64522;
}

.social .fa-linkedin:hover {
    color: #0094BC;

}
.fill {  
    min-height: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
} 
html, body { 
    height: 100%; 

    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

And this is the current output:
[image]

As you may see, there are two columns, one with red background and one with yellow background.
I would like both columns to have the height space from header to footer.
I have tried putting in style: height=100%, but doesn´t work.

What should I change to get both columns height to the remaining space between header and footer?

Answer (score 0):

Defining height might not directly affect the height of the `div`, try to explicitly tell the `div` to be of a minimum height by using *`min-height`*.

Comment: thank you, but same result with your proposal